# computed property in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, computed-properties

I'm trying to make a spinning wheel in objective-C by replicating [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/107687/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-spinning-wheel) tutorial. But i have no idea how to convert swift's computed property in objective c. How can i declare radius variable in objective-c like below code where i can call invalidateLayout method in the computed variable ?

```
var radius: CGFloat = 500 {
  didSet {
    invalidateLayout()
  }
}
```

Comment: You should implement a radius property and the setRadius (setter) method, too.

Comment: computed property is using "get" or "set", not "didSet". What you mean is Property Observers.
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly spoken your example is not a computed property

Anyway the Objective-C equivalent is

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGFloat radius;
```

At some time set the initial value via the instance variable to get the behavior not to call the `invalidateLayout` method on initialization.

```
_radius = 500.0;
```

And implement the setter

```
- (void)setRadius:(CGFloat)radius
{
  if (_radius != radius) {
    _radius = radius;
    [self invalidateLayout];
  }
}
```

If you need to call always `invalidateLayout` even if the value doesn't change remove the `if` check.

Comment: Also, if you implement a setter, you need to implement a getter too, as it will not be auto-synthetized.

Comment: Good point, thanks, but AFAIK the getter is auto-synthesized.

Comment: You just corrupted correct answer, and make it wrong. Automatic KVO support is provided by `NSObject` and is by default available for all properties of a class that are key-value coding compliant. So you don't need to implement will/didChangeValueForKey. Moreover, if you do, you should also implement `automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:`

Comment: Thanks @BorisVerebsky I removed the lines

Comment: You're right Boris, I was wrong about KVO. Bad habits die hard. I'm removing my comments now.